# ReactJS Nested Property Not Available for JSON Data

Tags: json, reactjs

I am trying to capture a nested property within my JSON file that I have loaded into my state, but for some reason, despite logging that the property exists within the object, when I use dot-notation to navigate a level deeper if throws the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

Why would it recognize the first-level and log the second-level, but not allow the second-level to be accessed with dot-notation? Am I missing a nuance that is unique to React?

**JSON:**

```
{
    ...
    "avg_distribution_sleep_type": {
        "x": [22.37484390963787, 62.65183335225337, 14.973322738108752],
        "labels": ["deep", "light", "rem"]
    },
    ...
}
```

**Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import SleepData from '../../../public/data/sleep_data.json';

class BarChart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if(process.env.NODE_ENV == "development"){
            this.setState({
                data: SleepData
            });
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.data.avg_distribution_sleep_type.x);
        console.log(this.myRef);
        return <>
            <div ref={this.myRef}>Testing Refs</div>
        </>
    }
}

export default BarChart;
```

**Console Log (this.state.data.avg_distribution_sleep_type):**

```
{x: Array(3), labels: Array(3)}
labels: (3) ["deep", "light", "rem"]
x: (3) [22.37484390963787, 62.65183335225337, 14.973322738108752]
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is expected in prod you will definitely get error for this `console.log(this.state.data.avg_distribution_sleep_type.x);`

just check `this.state` has `avg_distribution_sleep_type` and `x`

and then do your things.

UPDATE:

```
if('avg_distribution_sleep_type' in this.state.data) {
 console.log(this.state.data.avg_distribution_sleep_type.x);
}
```

UPDATE: Another approach

```
render() {
        // nothing will show unless you get the data. 
        if (!this.state.data.length) return <></>;

        

        console.log(this.state.data.avg_distribution_sleep_type.x);
        console.log(this.myRef);
        return <>
            <div ref={this.myRef}>Testing Refs</div>
        </>
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why will I definitely get an error? How do I access the "x" property nested within the `avg_distribution_sleep_type` property? As you can see in my question, the first level returns the properties in the second-level, x and labels, but when I try to access x with dot notation it throws an error

Comment: Okay I think I understand now. So what you are trying to say is that it is possible that my code could be executing faster than the setting of the `this.state.data` value, which is why the error is thrown. Your code above works, but is there a better approach to capturing this when the state is loaded rather than using a conditional to check? I will accept your answer, but wonder if there is a better approach